# Call Power BI API in Power Query

Tags: powershell, api, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to retrieve data from Power BI API services and the same is being accomplished via PowerShell code. But unfortunately due to some circumstances I am not able to deploy it in production. Hence now I am trying to get the same thing done in Power BI desktop itself so that I can call power BI rest API from Power Query only. There are tons of blogpost about calling an API in power query but they all require Power BI App registered Client ID. Which I don't have. I'm successfully able to call with my user name password in PowerShell and even I'm getting response from API.

Please find below PowerShell code and let me know if we can replicate the same in Power Query.

```
# User credential
$User = 'shahab***@*****.com'
$Pword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String '***password***' –AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $User,$Pword

# Connect to service
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $Credential  

#Get Bearer token
$headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken  

$uri = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/f52f2abc-6445-41ee-ce02-3908c6e18dd4/refreshes' 
$refreshes = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method GET
$xs= $refreshes
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. You have a table from powershell,  but you can't deploy the results to production?  Are [you trying to refresh a dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup), when the powerquery is evaluated ? -- Power Query is not great on REST APIs, it's going to call the endpoint more times than you'd think because of isolating queries, and query editor previews. -- It seems like a XY question where there's other options, but I'm not totally clear on what you're doing.

Comment: Hi @ninMonkey

Thanks for your reply.

I'm trying get data from Power BI service and I'm using GET method.

This is done in PowerShell and we're able successfully retrieve the records as well.

same thing I want to do in Power Query using M Language

Answer (score 1):

With the wrapper, you want something like this.

```
WebRequest_Simple(
    "https://api.powerbi.com",
    "v1.0/myorg/datasets/f52f2abc-6445-41ee-ce02-3908c6e18dd4/refreshes",
    [
        Headers = [ Authorization = "Bearer OAuthTokenHere" ]
    ]
)
```

If the url had a query string (the part after `?`), then you'd use `options[Query]`

### Web Response

[image]

### Full Query

Source: [WebRequest_Simple.pq](https://github.com/ninmonkey/Ninmonkey.PowerQueryLib/blob/70a2253184b4c8942f9ecf36ef0bc10afcefa572/source/WebRequest_Simple.pq)

```
let    
    /*
    Wrapper for Web.Contents  returns response metadata 
        for options, see: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents#__toc360793395>

    */
    WebRequest_Simple
        =  (
            base_url as text,
            optional relative_path as nullable text,
            optional options       as nullable record
        )
        as record =>
        let 
    
            headers = options[Headers]?, //or: ?? [ Accept = "application/json" ],

            merged_options = [      
                Query = options[Query]?,
                RelativePath = relative_path,
                ManualStatusHandling = options[ManualStatusHandling]? ?? { 400, 404 },
                Headers = headers
            ],
        
            bytes = Web.Contents(base_url, merged_options),
            response = Binary.Buffer(bytes),
            response_metadata = Value.Metadata( bytes ),
            status_code = response_metadata[Response.Status]?,
            json = Json.Document(response),
            Final = [
                request_url = metadata[Content.Uri](),
                status_code = status_code,
                metadata = response_metadata,
                IsJson = not (try json)[HasError],
                response = response,
                json = json
            ]
        in 
            Final,

    tests = {
        WebRequest_Simple("https://httpbin.org", "json"), // expect: json
        WebRequest_Simple("https://www.google.com"),       // expect: html
        WebRequest_Simple(
            "https://api.powerbi.com",
            "v1.0/myorg/datasets/f52f2abc-6445-41ee-ce02-3908c6e18dd4/refreshes",
            [
                Headers = [ Authorization = "Bearer OAuthTokenHere" ]
            ]
        )
    },

    FinalResults = Table.FromRecords(tests,
        type table[
            status_code = text, request_url = text, metadata = record,
            response = binary, IsJson = logical, json = any],
        MissingField.Error
    )    
in
    FinalResults
```