# Building URL from first query to make URL for addl columsn and details. excel / powerquery

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to figure out how to add extended details generate from my first Json.Document Web.Contents query. Each record returns some variables that are used to generate a URL where I can query addition details for the items in each row. I think I have to make a function, but cannot figure out how to get this done for each row.

I've gotten the first query put together, and after a bit I figured out how to generate the URL needed for the extra information.

```
let
    url = "https://inventoryservice.website.com/Inventory/Search",
    body = 
      "{
        ""Locations"":[14,12,15,16,22],
        ""Models"":[99],
        ""ID"":13,
        ""Years"":[2020,2021]
      }",
    Headers = [
        #"Authority"="inventoryservice.website.com",
        #"Method"="POST",
        #"Accept"="*/*",
        #"Origin"="https://www.website.com",
        #"Referer"="https://www.website.com/",
        #"Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8",
        #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
        ],
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = Headers,Content = Text.ToBinary(body)])),

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"exact"}, {"Column1.exact"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.exact" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1.exact"),
    #"Expanded Column1.exact1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1.exact", "Column1.exact", {"longID", "ticketID", "lineID", "locID", "locName", "makeName", "modelName", "modelYear", "serial", "dateAdded"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1.exact1",{{"longID", Int64.Type}, {"ticketID", Int64.Type}, {"lineID", Int64.Type}, {"locID", Int64.Type}, {"locName", type text}, {"makeName", type text}, {"modelName", type text}, {"modelYear", Int64.Type},  {"serial", type text}, {"dateAdded", type datetime}}),

    /*BUILD URL COLUMN*/
    infoUrl = each "https://inventoryservice.website.com/InventoryExtendedInfo/" & Number.ToText([locID]) & "/" & Number.ToText([ticketID]) & "/" & Number.ToText([lineID]) & "/",
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", infoUrl)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

For additional details I can hard code the url and make a a one row table with the following, but I cannot figure out how to add the additional columns to the original matching record on the table.

```
let
    url = "https://inventoryservice.website.com/ExtendedInfo/14/1080204/1/",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(
        url,[ 
        Headers = [
            #"Authority"="inventoryservice.website.com",
            #"Method"="POST",
            #"Accept"="*/*",
            #"Origin"="https://www.website.com",
            #"Referer"="https://www.website.com/",
            #"Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8",
            #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
            ]
        ]
    )),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Converted to Table"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Type", type text}, {"SubType", type any}, {"style", type text}, {"color", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: Providing the query code isn't much helpful without providing the data. Add some sample data with expected output

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745142/call-power-bi-api-in-power-query/69400197#69400197 . You can use a regular `Table.AddColumn` to call `WebRequest_Simple`, where columns can be parameters